# Unable to set the Android sdk path for Eclipse?

Tags: android, eclipse

I have installed Android sdk and installed ADT pulgin as well on ubuntu 10.4.
But when i open eclipse. I got the below error message.

[image: Error Message when opening Eclipse]

Edit:
I have java already in my PC.

Comment: Probably you might need to download the platform tools - i.e. you have just installed sdk manager and not downloaded the sdk yet. Does open sdk manager opens up for you ?

Comment: I have downloaded android-sdk_r20.0.3-linux.tgz from http://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html

Comment: I have already installed java in my pc.

Answer (score 11, accepted):

Open Eclipse and go to Preferences  (Window -> Preferences), select the Android tab and Browse to you SDK location.

If this not works try to reinstall Android SDK

Comment: [2012-10-24 17:34:12 - DeviceMonitor] Connection attempts: 1
This is the error i got in console.

Answer (score 4):

I am adding those two pictures to have it visually **archived** for me and others! GoogleDorks: "Where is the SDK-Path for Android in Eclipse"

1) Window > Preferences

[image]

2) Android

[image]