# Eclipse Android: Could not find SDK Folder?

Tags: android, eclipse, sdk, adt, eclipse-luna

I have downloaded `SDK tools` from [here](https://developer.android.com/sdk/index.html?hl=i)  and installed the `ADT Plugin` for `Eclipse Luna.`

I can see the `SDK manager` and `AVD manager` icons in the toolbar, but when I click on the SDK manager I get the error:

```
 "Could not find SDK folder."
```

And when I click on the `AVD manager` I get:

```
"Location of the Android SDK has not been set up in the preferences."
```

How can I solve this problem, I assume that I need to find the location of my SDK folder, but I am not sure how to do this then set it in Eclipse?

Answer (score 0):

```
Open Eclipse and go to Preferences (Window -> Preferences), select the Android tab and Browse to you SDK location.
```

[Unable to set the Android sdk path for Eclipse](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/13047711/unable-to-set-the-android-sdk-path-for-eclipse)

Comment: I have done so, but then within the screen I am not able to set the location, I get the error "Could not find folder 'tools' inside SDk" ?

Comment: which os do u have like windows and mac and so on also download new sdk

Comment: I have windows operating system?